# 3D point plot - visualization

Tags: plot

I've some points of the form (*a*+i*b*, *c*) where *a,b,c* are real numbers. I.e. "(complex number, real number)".

I would like to visualize these points in a 3D plot such that the *x,y*-plane represents the complex plane and the *z*-axis measures the 
*c* value/ second coordinate.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! You may want to take a look at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ and its section "4.6.4 Scatter Plots" (below Three Dimensional Plot Types).